# Laravel 4 - Linking posts to the appropriate subject

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eloquent

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get my posts to display under the same subject. I'm currently porting over procedural code where posts have a subject_id that linked to the subject id in the db.

**Example:**

Subject 1

- Related post 1
- Related post 2

Subject 2

- Related post 1
- Related post 2

The area I don't understand fully comprehend after looking at similar Stack posts is where the subject/post are connected in the model. Right now the code is just showing all subjects and posts but not displaying the posts assigned to the same subject.

Help in understanding what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all subjects
    $subjects = Subjects::all();
    // $subjects = Subjects::with('pages')->get();
    $pages = Pages::all();

    // Load the view and pass in the subjects
    // return View::make('index')->with('subjects', $subjects)->with('pages', $pages);
    return View::make('index', compact('subjects', 'pages'));
}
```

**Subjects Model**

```
class Subjects extends Eloquent {

public function pages ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Pages', 'subject_id');
}

}
```

**Posts Model**

```
class Pages extends Eloquent {

public function subjects ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Subjects', 'id');
}

}
```

**View**

```
    @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
            <tr>
                <td> {{ $subject->menu_name }} </td><br>
            </tr>

            @foreach ($pages as $page_id)
            <tr>
                <li>{{ $page_id->menu_name }}</li><br>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load each subject's pages by calling `$subject->pages` in your loop:

**Controller**:

```php
public function index()
{    
    return View::make('index')->withSubjects( Subjects::with('Pages')->get() );
}
```

**Note:** For efficiency, we're calling `with('Pages')` in the controller, to [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) the pages.

---

**View**:

```html
@foreach ($subjects as $subject)

    <tr>
        <td> {{ $subject->menu_name }} </td>
    </tr>

    @foreach ($subject->pages as $page)
    <tr>
        <li>{{ $page->menu_name }}</li>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: How does the code in the model forms look? Made the changes as you have suggested and came up with the follow error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$pages (View: /var/www/laravel_guestbook/app/views/index.blade.php)

Comment: @KansasCityShuffle - Are you sure you have `$subject->pages` in your view, and not `$subjects->pages`?

Comment: My mistake I used subjects->pages instead of "subject"->pages. Thank you so much in your solution, I'll need to go back and fully understand the code you suggested in the controller and view.

Comment: Could you quickly step through and explain the code in the controller?

Comment: @KansasCityShuffle - **a)** `withSubjects(...)` is just a shortcut to `with('subjects', ...)`. **b)** `Subjects::with('Pages')->get()` is the same as `Subjects::all()`, but [eager loads](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) the pages.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the quick break down sir! Many, many thanks!